# What's a good textbook to learn about Diffraction in Optics?

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I am taking a course in Fundamental of physics for Chemists, Below is the areas I want to learn

- Franhouofer diffraction
- Rectangular and circular apertures
- resolving power
- Single slit
- double slit and diffraction grating
- x-ray diffraction
- Ion production
- Anuring of ions in mass
- spectrometers
- Ion mirrors
- Ion selection,
- Ion gates
- MS-MS

Any help with the topic would be appreciated

Comment: To the close voters: resource recommendations are on topic (cf. [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)).